# Parse JSON to custom 'tree-like' file structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have a folder/file system of custom classes, where Folders can have childs of either Folders or Files. Files cannot have children. When I have added folders and files, I would like to save the structure to be able to restore it. Right now i store the structure as a JSON string and my problem is how to parse it back to the custom classes.

A JSON string could look like:

```
{
  "name": "Root",
  "type": "Folder",
  "img": null,
  "checked": false,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Folder1",
      "type": "Folder",
      "img": "img/folder.png",
      "checked": false,
      "children": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Desert.jpg",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "img": "img/file.png",
      "checked": false,
      "data": {
        "lastModifiedDate": "2009-07-14T05:32:31.000Z",
        "size": 845941
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where children with `type ==='Folder'` is of my custom Folder class and `type !== 'Folder'` is an object of my custom File class.

How should i parse this JSON to be able to create new custom objects and store them in my file structure?
I have tried to do this, but i get stuck at the first level. I'm not that good at recursion which I suppose that I should do.
My code so far that works when there is only files/folders in the root and no subfolders/subfiles

```
function importJson(json){
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
    //This line needs to be fixed when/if recursion?
    var currentFolder = rootFolder; //a global variable which is my rootFolder

    for(var i = 0, obj = jsonObj.children; i < obj.length; i++){
        if(obj[i].type === 'Folder'){
            var folder = new Folder(obj[i].name, 'Folder');
            folder.img = obj[i].img;
            currentFolder.add(folder);
            console.log('A folder, check for children?');
        }
        else{
            var file = new File(obj[i].name, obj[i].type);
            file.data = obj[i].data;
            file.img = obj[i].img;
            currentFolder.add(file);
            console.log('a file');
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use recursion. Have your method accept the parsed JSON as a parameter instead of parsing it in the function, then when you need to check for children in a folder, simply call your method again with the folder you want to parse, in this case `obj[i]`.

Comment: Thanks, this was simpler than expected. Had to change my currentFolder so that everything wasn't added to the root.